# unable to store a data value into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am unable to store the data in the MySQL database.
url1 data -> is not forwarding to the u1.php.

I am unable to get through this. While running this query on u1.php with a dummy valve it's perfect:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE admins SET url1 = '1234568' WHERE id = '1'");
```

When I check the DB it is perfect with the above value, but when I try form data url1 is not working.

```
<form action="u1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Select The File:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp; Enter Ad Url :<input type="text" name="url1" id="url1" placeholder="Please Enter Ad Url" width: 500px;>    <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**u1.php file**

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("apphp");
    mysql_query("UPDATE admins SET url1 = '$url1' WHERE id = '1'");




    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 350000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/h1.jpg");
        echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";

  }
?>
```

Comment: *"not working"* doesn't really tell us anything, chances are MySQL is throwing an error, you should use `mysql_error()` if the `mysql_query()` does not return success.

Comment: You're not setting `$url1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `$url1` before using it in the query.

```
if (isset($_POST['url1'])) {
    $url1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url1']);
} else {
    die ("Ad URL is required.");
}
mysql_query("UPDATE admins SET url1 = '$url1' WHERE id = '1'");
```

Comment: iam getting error message Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'
please see the next code
i had added the condition on u1.php file

Comment: Was missing a parenthesis, fixed. You couldn't figure that out yourself?